# Unable to launch GCC, it crashes

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, ntvdm

I am using GCC 3.4.4 through Cygwin on Windows 7 x64. It has work flawlessly for a long time. Now GCC has recently stopped working with an error everytime it's launched:

> gcc.exe
>
> The NTVDM CPU has encountered a illegal instruction
>
> CS:0000 IP0075 OP:f0 00 f0 37 05 Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.

I've tried re-installing GCC through cygwin, and i've tried adding full permissions on the file for all users.

How can this be solved?

Comment: if you try MinGW, has it the same problem?

Comment: I havn't used minGW. Is it available from cygiwn too?

Comment: no; they are something similar, https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cygwin#Alternatives I've used MinGW just to have the gcc on Windows, and never tried cygwin, so I cant say if MinGW can satisfy your need as cygwin; though, it was just to test if "another" gcc works or doesn't

Comment: Hopefully there's just a way to fix GCC; if not, I'll just go back to VS.

Comment: It's 7 years old. Isn't it time to move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long ago I had a similar problem which seemed to affect like every third program.  After hours and hours of searching, the cause was that the Cygwin virtual volume had the mount parameters messed up.  It was doing newline translation when it should not have been (or vice versa).